# Electricity from something other than a solid

Tags: material-science, electrical-engineering

Is piezoelectricity only limited to solids or can liquids or non-Newtonian fluids create a current when compressed?

Answer (score 1):

Piezoelectricity, at least in the usual meaning of the word, arises when you deform a material that does not have a centre of symmetry i.e. there is no inversion symmetry. Liquids are amorphous and therefore (on average) isotropic. This means they are inversionally symmetric (about any point in fact) and therefore will not generate piezoelectricity when compressed.

Answer (score 1):

Piezoelectricity has been found in liquid crystals too, see for ex. see RB Meyer, Physical Review Letters 22, 918 (1969).

To show piezoelectricity, a material needs some degree of anisotropy; thus it would hardly be possible to find piezoelectricity in liquids, which are pretty isotropic.